# How to separate the Ubuntu System track and clock from the main Ubuntu Dock panel in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-clocks

I upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10.

My dock panel settings and the application button settings transferred over. I was playing around with the GNOME Tweaks app, and selected Dash to Panel. This has now moved the system clock and system tray to the Ubuntu Dock panel.

I prefer to have the clock and system tray in the top panel as it was in Ubuntu 18.04. How do I change this back?